# Connect php to a dropdown in php coding

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I want to connect phpmyadmin to a dropdown box in my phpcoding. So when I go to my webpage, I want to have a dropdown menu that shows the first column in my phpmyadmin table.

Here is my coding:

```
<form name="editcustomer" method="get" action="editcustomersubmit.php"> 
   Surname:<select>
           <?php 
           include 'db.php'; 
           while($row = mysql_query("SELECT Surname FROM customer")){  
               <option> $row['Surname']; </option> 
           } 
           ?>
           </select>
```

Sorry as this is my first time posting.

The db.php just connects the php to the database. In this, I have

```
<?php mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error()); mysql_select_db("db name") or die(mysql_error()); ?>
```

When I run this script, I just get a dropdown menu that has many blank values. Everything else that is on that page gets removed.

Thanks

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: @Cameron: phpmyadmin just provides an interface to your MySQL database. phpmyadmin is not a database itself

Comment: @Cameron: and also what is the code in your `db.php` ?

Comment: also i have noticed that your line `<option> $row['Surname']; </option> ` is incorrect. it must be `echo "<option>" . $row['Surname'] . "</option>"; `.. Please show us any error you're receiving and complete code..

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is just an interface to to the underlying MySQL database. That said, your PHP script shouldn't care about phpMyAdmin -- it's the MySQL database that's important for it.

First, you need it to execute the query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Surname FROM customer");
```

It's usually good idea to check whether the query failed(due invalid syntax, missing table or column, broken table or something else):

```
if (!$result) {
    die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Now, in `$result` you have a resource that should be be used with some of the `mysql_*` functions. It's important to understand the resource itself isn't useful, because only functions from `mysql` library know how to deal with it.

Then, you need to print the options in the select box:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
   echo '<option>' . $row['Surname'] . '</option>'; 
}
```

Pay attention to the syntax. You can't just mix HTML and PHP code -- there is separation between them. The `echo` call is printing the string to the browser.

Note that there are 2 issues with your code:

- you need to enable error reporting. Look up error reporting in PHP documentation for more information on this
- You're going to need a `value` attribute on the option tag in order save changes done in the select box

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. Thanks for the help.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("fleet hire motors") or die(mysql_error());
$query=mysql_query("SELECT CustomerID FROM customer") or die(mysql_error());
$numfields = mysql_num_fields($query);
print("<select name='customerid'>\n\n");
for ($i=0; $i<$numfields; $i++) {
;
}
;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
print("<option>\n");
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($row); $i++) {
  printf("%s\n", $row[$i]);
}
print("</option>\n");
}
print("</select>\n");
?>
```